# REGEX to last set of parentheses PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
    (require|include)(_once)?(?|\(([^)]+)\)| ([^\s;]+))
```

it will find the following without a problem:

```
    require(foo);
    require_once(foo);
    require foo;
    require_once foo;
    include(foo);
    include_once(foo);
    include foo;
    include_once foo;
```

but the problem i am have is some code that looks like:

```
    require(foo() . bar());
```

So when the code runs it is doing:

```
    require(somefunction(foo()) . bar());
```

which is ending the new function at the first ) instead of at );

alright got it working using:

```
    (require|include)(_once)?(?|[^\(]*\((.*)\)[\);$+]*| ([^\s;]+))
```

however it works until there is a comment so if the line looks like:

```
    include(foo); // Some comment include()
```

which when ran ends with:

```
    include(somefunction(foo);
```

missing one of the closing parentheses because of the comment. please note i cannot remove comment

needed to add in an end ; to take care of this so final result was:

```
    (require|include)(_once)?(?|[^\(]*\((.*)\);[\);$+]*| ([^\s;]+))
```

Comment: Finding matching brackets with a frontal and reverse loop is much more secure than a regular expression (given that brackets are not part of a regular language, as far as I remember)...

Comment: this being used for modifying vqmod from opencart to work with codeigniter framework. so i have very little wiggle room to modify the way things work without making it a pain to update and remember everything i did each time.

Comment: so where would the dollar sign go? I am not a wiz at regex. I don't work with it often

Comment: If you're trying to use regexps to parse PHP scripts, why not use the built-in [PHP tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.tokenizer.php) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your input strings as fitting 1 of 2 possible cases: those where `require` or `insert` **have parentheses**, and those where they **do not have parentheses**.

#### Demonstration

```
<?php

$strings = array(
  'require(foo);',
  'require_once(foo);',
  'require foo;',
  'require_once foo;',
  'include(foo);',
  'include_once(foo);',
  'include foo;',
  'include_once foo;',
  'require(foo() . bar());');

foreach($strings as $string) {
  $with_paren = '((require|include)(_once)?\()(.*)\);';
  $without_paren = '((require|include)(_once)? )(.*);';
  preg_match("/$with_paren|$without_paren/", $string, $matches);
  if (array_key_exists(1, $matches) && strlen($matches[1])) {
    print $string . " => " . $matches[1] . "somefunction(" . $matches[4] . "));\n";
  }
  else if (array_key_exists(5, $matches) && strlen($matches[5])) {
    print $string . " => " . $matches[5] . "somefunction(" . $matches[8] . ");\n";
  }
  else {
    print $string . " DID NOT MATCH\n";
  }

  // Uncomment below to see original string followed by array of match elements
  // print $string . "\n";
  // print_r($matches);
}
```

Resulting Output

```
require(foo); => require(somefunction(foo));
require_once(foo); => require_once(somefunction(foo));
require foo; => require somefunction(foo);
require_once foo; => require_once somefunction(foo);
include(foo); => include(somefunction(foo));
include_once(foo); => include_once(somefunction(foo));
include foo; => include somefunction(foo);
include_once foo; => include_once somefunction(foo);
require(foo() . bar()); => require(somefunction(foo() . bar()));
```

#### Explanation

You'll notice that the key lines of code are the following:

```
  $with_paren = '((require|include)(_once)?\()(.*)\);';
  $without_paren = '((require|include)(_once)? )(.*);';
  preg_match("/$with_paren|$without_paren/", $string, $matches);
```

I just broke it into `$with_paren` and `$without_paren` strings, but the entire regular expression could have been written as one line:

```
  ((require|include)(_once)?\()(.*)\);|((require|include)(_once)? )(.*);
```

My code examples uses PHP's `preg_match` function, which searches for a match against your regular expression and then puts matching elements into an array, which I've named `$matches`.  More information on `preg_match` can be [found here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

If your input string is of the *has parentheses* case, then you'll have a string at `$matches[1]` (since that is the first sub-expression which was matched).  If your input string is of the *does not have parentheses* case, then you'll have a string at `$matches[5]` (since that is the fifth sub-expression which was matched).

The PHP code I've provided checks to see which type of match has occurred, and then it outputs a rewrite of the original string, but now with your `somefunction(...)` inserted.  Of course, that's just for demonstration purposes so that you can see that it works.  Hope that the regular expression is helpful to you.

Comment: thank you for the explanation and reference. Although what was provided for the examples didn't work for my particular situation it lead me in the right direction see the question for final answer

Answer (score 0):

With the idea of your pattern, you can change it to:

```
(require|include)(_once)?(?|(\(((?>[^()]++|(?-2))*)\))#\(([^)]+)\)|( )([^\s;]+))
```

Note that parenthesis content is now in the next capturing group.